# How do i make text start going on a new line with angular/bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Write now my message text is all going to be on one single line like this:

I would like it to start wrapping like iPhone text messages, is there anyway to do it programatically? insert br tags every 20 chars?
The actual message is the {{message.message}}

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-8 chatWindow">
  <div ng-show="activeFriend">
    <div class="activeFriendBox text-center">Chat with {{activeFriend.name}}</div>

    <div class="messageList" scroll-glue>
      <div class="messages"  
        ng-class="{ 'message-right': message.from === currentUser, 'message-left': message.from !==currentUser }" 
        ng-repeat='message in activeFriend.messages track by $index | orderBy:"timeStamp"'>
        <span 
          ng-class="{ 'messageTextFrom': message.from === currentUser, 'messageTextTo': message.from !==currentUser }"
          ng-click="revokeMessage(message)" class="messageText">{{message.message}} 
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sendMessage">
      <form ng-submit='sendMessage(messageText)' name='messageForm'>
        <input class="sendMessageInput" type='text' name='message' ng-model='messageText' maxlength="120" required/>
        <input ng-disabled='!messageForm.$valid || !activeFriend.key' type='submit' value='send'/>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with just CSS. Set a width on the container and also use `word-break: break-all;`

With the break-all, you can be assured that long consecutive strings, like the one in your example, will wrap in the space defined in your style sheet. You may also need to add `white-space:normal;` but it will all depend on the browsers you are required to support.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom filter to split the string every 20 characters.

```
angular.filter('split',function(){
    return function(str,length) {
       str = str || "";
       length = Math.max(1,~~length);
       return str.match(new RegExp(".{1,"+length+"}","g")).join("<br>");
    }
});
```

Then you can just use the filter in your template.

```
    <span 
      ng-class="{ 'messageTextFrom': message.from === currentUser, 'messageTextTo': message.from !==currentUser }"
      ng-click="revokeMessage(message)" class="messageText">{{message.message | split:20}} 
    </span>
```